# Can't ping between computers in same network

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, ping

I have three machines:
Windows 10; Windows 7 and; Ubuntu 20.04

**I cannot ping between these machines ...**

- The IP address Windows 10 is 192.168.1.45
- The IP address Windows 7 is 192.168.1.55
- The IP address Windows 10 is 192.168.1.70

These three machines are in the same subnet I am using optical fibers Home Gateway unit Product model is Earth-4222

Should I make changes inside the router?

When I try to ping from Ubuntu I get this error:

```
    midhun@midhun-Vostro-15-3568:~$ ping 192.168.1.45
    PING 192.168.1.45 (192.168.1.45) 56(84) bytes of data.
    From 192.168.1.70 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 192.168.1.70 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I tried this command on a Windows machine

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ping" protocol=ICMPV4 dir=in action=allow
```

Please help me to troubleshoot this issue.

When I tried traceroute from the Ubuntu machine to the Windows machine I got a result like this:

```
 midhun@midhun-Vostro-15-3568:~$ traceroute 192.168.1.45
    traceroute to 192.168.1.45 (192.168.1.45), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
     1  midhun-Vostro-15-3568.bbrouter (192.168.1.37)  2765.751 ms !H  2765.687 ms !H  2765.643 ms !H
```

The packets are not going to the router.

When I tried like this it passes through my router:

```
midhun@midhun-Vostro-15-3568:~$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  EARTH-4222.bbrouter (192.168.1.1)  7.253 ms  4.844 ms  4.817 ms
 2  10.208.224.1 (10.208.224.1)  6.050 ms  6.031 ms  6.012 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  72.14.218.250 (72.14.218.250)  23.782 ms  22.506 ms  22.464 ms
 7  * * *
 8  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  18.320 ms  18.536 ms  19.595 ms
```

Comment: Can you try to connect directly two machine (bypass the router/switch) and try to ping again ?

Comment: i shall try that and will reply soon

Comment: All 3x machines are on the same LAN (`192.168.1.x`), so this is a **switching** issue, not a routing issue. There is nothing to change/fix in the router.

Comment: @S.Brottes Yes i am able to ping

Comment: @SamAndrew81 I am very much new to these things ...I am using a GX Earth 4222 home gateway unit and connect all computers to the lan port...For this to be implemented ..should i buy some switching device

Comment: Try a `traceroute` (Ubuntu) or `tracert` (Windows) command to see where the packet is being blocked:  #from the Win10 machine @ 192.168.1.45 - `tracert 192.168.1.55`

Comment: The router has a switch in it already, you're good. The ethernet ports on the router are a switch (it's a combo unit). It you're using WiFi the same concept applies.

Comment: @SamAndrew81 ..I shall try that with in few minitues and shall report it back

Comment: @SamAndrew81 I have tried traceroute from ubuntu to my windows machine and have editted my doubt portion... To be frank i couldn't understand correctly what the output says

Comment: @MidhunRaj, try completely turning off the Windows Firewall - if that allows pings though, then there's your issue.

Comment: On Ubuntu the command to disable the firewall is `sudo systemctl stop ufw`

Comment: Since it works when directly connected, it's probably related to interconnexion elements. You can try to check if there is nothing like "Access list" configured on the routeur/switch. Moreover, be sure that both system are on the same switching domain. Some interface of the router can be on different switching domain preventing devices to communicate directly. Switching domain are generaly physicaly identify by color of the port and proximity between port. So be sure to connect the two devices on port of the same color and close to each other.

Comment: @S.Brottes thanks  for the suggestion will definitely try that